# hook_form_alter() to make multiple fields as required

Tags: forms

I am trying to make field(s) of Entity Form as required. The field(s) that I want to make required works fine when its one field but when I mention that a field(s) can accept unlimited values the required field(s) doesn't work. In other words only first field becomes required and not all other fields which user adds after pressing "Add another Item" button.

I am trying to hook_form_alter() but still I am not able to achieve where all additional fields become required when user presses add new item button. 
Below is the code that I wrote.

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
{

```
print_r($form_id);

if ($form_id == 'my_form_name') {

drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form, true) . '</pre>');


$form['my_field_name']['und']['0']['#required'] = TRUE;

}
```

}

Comment: you may want to take a look at this issue on DO -> [Issues with "required, multiple" fields in forms](https://www.drupal.org/node/980144#comment-9957753)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, patch did not work for me. Any other tip to fix this issue.